# EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on calling Appcelerator Module

Tags: appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

I am working with Appcelerator module. On Device I get EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error while I call the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I was using version 1.0, instead of 0.1, so, error was there. ;)